# How can i merge philips hue mesh with mqtt mesh in home assistant?

Tags: zigbee, home-assistant

My setup is as follows:

Home assistant running on a VM server with CC2531 zigbee2mqtt USB stick.
Next to server there is a Philips Hue hub.

I have a number of Hue lights and switches connected to Philips Hue hub. This is integrated using Philips Hue integration to Home Assistant.
I have some Aqara sensors I'm connecting to Home Assistant via USB stick. And integrated using MQTT into home assistant.

Lights/switches work throughout the house - mesh is working correctly. Some devices are pretty far away.
Aqara sensors ( they are all end devices ) are not working too far from USB stick.

This leads me to believe that at this point i have two separate zibgee meshes - one native philips hue and one for aqara.

How can i merge those two meshes ? I guess I'd have to do away with philips hue bridge and merge all philips devices into mqtt mesh ? Is there another way ?

Thanks,

B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either decide to use only your Z2M mesh and discard Hue. That needs to pair all devices from the Hue bridge to the CC2531 and Z2M. Keep in mind that CC2531 has limited resources and you can encounter issues if you have too many devices.

What I suggest is to keep two distinct networks but move some of the bulbs to the Z2M mesh in order to use them as relays, especially for your furthest Aqara end devices.